# How is the Earth an approximate inertial frame? How can one validate this?

Tags: reference-frames, inertial-frames, earth, approximations

I have always been confused by the idea of Earth being an approximately inertial frame as the speed at which it rotates is so high. Everywhere vaguely it is referred through calculation it can be seen that the frame is approximately inertial, what calculation would it be and is it compared to a theoretical model.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

It is not relative speed that prevents a reference frame being approximately an inertial frame of reference - it is acceleration. The acceleration due to the earth's rotation about its axis is relatively small - even at the equator it only amounts to about $0.3 \%$ of the acceleration due to gravity. So for many purposes it can be ignored.

So centrifugal force and Coriolis force (both of which arise only when working in a non-inertial frame of reference) have very little effect on the path of a baseball in flight or the motion of balls on a billiard table. However, when you look at motion on larger length scales or time scales, such as the motion of an artillery shell or a weather system or a Foucault pendulum, then they must be taken into account.

Comment: Note that centrifugal acceleration due to the Earth's rotation is typically folded into the local value of $g$, leaving only the Coriolis effect as a local non-inertial effect.

Answer (score 0):

Actually earth is an non-inertial frame because when earth is revolving around the sun,it also rotates about it's own axis.So angular velocity with which earth is moving changes a very very small amount which produces a small acceleration.But for our convinience, we consider that acceleration to be zero.So it can be treated as an inertial frame.

Answer (score -1):

There are strictly two types Earth frames in common usage. [Earth-centered inertial](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earth-centered_inertial)  (ECI) frames are centred at the centre of the Earth and do not rotate with respect to the stars. Earth-centered, Earth-fixed (ECEF) frames are fixed with respect to Earth's surface. Only the ECI frames are approximately inertial.

Comment: Over sufficiently short distances and for sufficiently small velocities, and Earth-centered, Earth-fixed frame can be treated as approximately inertial.